# Apache Derby not giving response

Tags: java, derby

I am trying out a sample using Apache Derby.

I have created a web project in which on my servlet i am creating Derby 
connection as:

```
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:resultDataDB;create=true";
    private static String tableName = "RESULTMAPPING";

private void createConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then i am creating the Table as :

```
private void createTableStructure() {
        try{
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("create table " +tableName+ " (id integer,resultName varchar(200),resutlValue varchar(300))");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The above piece of code runs once only.
Then i insert some records and then i am trying to fetch the records with the below method:

```
protected String getResultName(String resultValue){
        String resultVal=null;
        if(resultValue.contains("#")){
            resultVal = resultValue.split("#")[1];
        }else{
            resultVal = resultValue;
        }
        System.out.println("query parameter: " + resultVal);
        String resultName=null;
        try
        {
            String query = "select resultName from APP." + tableName + " where RESUTLVALUE=?";
            PreparedStatement preStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preStmt.setString(1, resultVal);
            ResultSet results = preStmt.executeQuery();
            while(results.next())
            {
                resultName= results.getString(1);
                System.out.println("resultName : " + resultName);

            }
            results.close();
            preStmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultName;
    }
```

I have created a JAVA Project as well with the above piece of code. Now here comes the strange part. When i run the above method in JavaProject then i get the expected result but when i try to invoke the Same method when invoking the web project. I don't get any result.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't get any result"? Do you mean you don't see your `System.out.println` output? Maybe that output is going to a different location and you aren't looking in the right place. Code that is run in a web server needs to return its results as HTML data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bryan. Well the problem was i was inserting data to the table through Main method and when i tried to do a select through the web page. It didn't gave me any result related to select query.

Comment: So to solve the issue i had to insert data using the web project.. That solved the issue..

Comment: Ah. It sounds like using a relative database name in your JDBC Connection URL (`jdbc:derby:resultDataDB;create=true`) is what confused you. Using one copy of your program, you inserted data into one copy of `resultDataDB` in one location on your hard disk. Then, when you ran another copy of your program via the web server, it didn't find the original copy of the database (because it looked in a different location on your hard disk) and instead created a second copy of the database.